# Is it safe to use the 12W iPad 4th gen power adapter for earlier iPads and iPhones?

Tags: iphone, charging, charger, ipad

The older iPads have 10W power adapter (charger), and the iPhones supposed use only 5W chargers.

But the iPad 4th gen, probably due to the larger power consumption, uses a 12W power adapter / charger.

Is this charger safe to use with the older iPads and iPhones.  Will it overcharge or overheat or damage the battery?  A more serious worry is that if it overheats, then can the battery explode?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The wattage ratings are maximum and all iOS devices will only pull the current they need to charge.

Should a device or an adapter get too hot to operate safely, they will shut off.